# How can I kill a process (WinAmp) stuck on startup and not agreeing to die?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, winamp

I've just started WinAmp after a couple of months of not using it (I have the latest version you can get from not-their-website through winamp.com). Window comes up, but most panes are blank rectangles, and the UI won't respond. [x] ing at the top right corner doesn't work. Task Manager End Process - no effect. It doesn't show on the taskbar. If I wait for about, say, 1.5-3 minutes or so, it does die.

Why can this process (which is not privileged, or a system process, or what not) resist my attempts to kill it? How can I kill it immediately? (Sorry for the brutal and violent question...)

Answer (score 2):

Run [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), select the Winamp process, make a right click and select "Terminator":

[image]

Here you can run several ways to terminate a process.

Answer (score 1):

1. Some processes show in the *Details* pane of Task Manager that do not appear in the *Processes* pane.
2. MS/SysInternal's [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) might provide you with more detail yet; if a process is balky, there's an option under the *File* menu to restart Process Explorer as Administrator.
3. You may need to kill the *process tree* (the process and any child process), easily done in Process Explorer. There is a thread on this, using the command line, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528963/taskkill-f-doesnt-kill-a-process.